# How to call function using objc in Rust

Tags: objective-c, macos, rust

I want to run a function of Cocoa's Quartz Window Services on Mac called [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo) using a library called [`objc`](https://crates.io/crates/objc) from Rust, is it possible?
I can't figure out how to run function it with [`send_msg!`](http://sasheldon.com/rust-objc/objc/macro.msg_send.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're linking to the Swift version of the API, you *really* want [the objective C version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo?language=objc).

Second, Objective-C is for "methods" on objects, that is why `send_msg!` takes a subject (`obj`). `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` is part of a "core" service, which means it's pretty much straight C. Now I don't know if there are bindings for that, apparently Servo once maintained CG bindings but it seems like they're deprecated. You can probably BYO as if you were binding to a regular C library (by hand or using bindgen).

I would recommend learning how macOS APIs and frameworks work first, though.